# Casting a Type for JSON Object's Values in Java

Tags: java, json, casting, dropwizard

Inside of my DropWizard Java 7 project I have a resource that consumes JSON (org.json.simple.JSONObject). Inside of the JSON are three keys, the first two include a list of IDs with the last key holding a list of list of Strings.

The difficulties I am running into is when I am casting the types for the values of each of these keys. From what I understand, since Java does not know the object types of the JSON values until runtime I can cast the values based on the objects I am using.

```
@POST
@Timed
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<TwitterUserWithSocialGraph> getTwitterRelationships(JSONObject j) {
    Set<Long> idListOne = (Set<Long>) j.get("id_list_one");
    Set<Long> idListTwo = (Set<Long>) j.get("id_list_two");
    Set<ArrayList<String>> stringSet = (Set<ArrayList<String>>) j.get("stringSet");
```

When I start the server, however, I continuously receive for the id lists a collection of type ArrayList. Considering that perhaps Java can hold the ids I am passing in can be either Integer or Longs (which is true, some IDs could be stored as an Integer but I need Longs since most of them do not) I instead attempt to cast the Set with Objects.

```
@POST
@Timed
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<TwitterUserWithSocialGraph> getTwitterRelationships(JSONObject j) {
    Set<Object> idListOne = (Set<Object>) j.get("id_list_one");
    Set<Object> idListTwo = (Set<Object>) j.get("id_list_two");
    Set<ArrayList<String>> stringSet = (Set<ArrayList<String>>) j.get("stringSet");
```

Again I still receive an ArrayList as the collection type for the ID lists. Therefore I try:

```
@POST
@Timed
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<TwitterUserWithSocialGraph> getTwitterRelationships(JSONObject j) {
    ArrayList<Object> idListOne = (ArrayList<Object>) j.get("id_list_one");
    ArrayList<Object> idListTwo = (ArrayList<Object>) j.get("id_list_two");
    Set<ArrayList<String>> stringSet = (Set<ArrayList<String>>) j.get("stringSet");
```

Now, however, I'll have to rebuild the arraylists to store Longs and then place these Longs into a Set. Clearly I am overlooking how to properly cast my types so that at runtime the proper types I want are set. Unless, of course, there is a different implementation I should be using.

If I try:

```
@POST
@Timed
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<TwitterUserWithSocialGraph> getTwitterRelationships(JSONObject j) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Set<Long> idSetOne = gson.fromJson(j.get("my_tw_ids").toString(), new TypeToken<Set<Long>>() {}.getType());
    Set<Long> idSetTwo = gson.fromJson(j.get("other_tw_ids").toString(), new TypeToken<Set<Long>>() {}.getType());
    Set<ArrayList<String>> stringSet = gson.fromJson(j.get("stringSet").toString(), new TypeToken<Set<ArrayList<String>>>() {}.getType());
```

GSON can cast the types I wish to use for the id sets but it cannot properly case the string set (a "malformed string" error is raised).

Can someone point me in the proper direction of how to best cast a set of longs as well as how to cast a set of string array lists?

Comment: In the last line of your last example, you're missing the closing quote for `stringSet`. Is that causing your issue?

Comment: If a value can be either Integer or Long and you need them in a common class use Number, the superclass of all the numeric "wrapper" classes.

Comment: Understand that "cast" does not change the actual class type of an object.  It merely states what class should be assumed for the reference.

Comment: And it kind of seems to me like you're jumping through all sorts of hoops to avoid writing a simple loop.

Comment: Ahh @Foxsly no it is there, sorry about that. I was editing the code and must have missed the closing quote.

Comment: @HotLicks casting the IDs as ArrayList<Number> does work however I was curious if there was an implementation that I was unaware of that did this. Alas I will use a foreach loop to add number.longValue() to the ID sets.

Comment: @HotLicks why am I restricted from being able to case the collection type as a Set? The type the collection holds as Number vs. Long/Integer I understand but why an ArrayList vs. a Set (the collection type I need) is still lost to me.

Comment: You may be able to convince one of the Jacksonesque JSON kits to return a Set, but the "natural" representation for JSON is Lists and Maps.  These map directly to JSON "arrays" and "objects".  Unless you specially direct the JSON parser to do differently you will get back some flavor of Lists and Maps.

Comment: And once again you can't cast an object to something it is not.  Ie, you cannot cast a List to a Set.  If you think you should be able to, you don't adequately understand object-oriented programming.